# How to dynamically create params for Cewolf ChartProcessor?

Tags: java, jfreechart, cewolf

I have an issue trying to create a pie chart in my JSP. I am using Cewolf (and Jfreechart). My code is the following :

```
<cewolf:chartpostprocessor id="pieChartPP">
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.statsClientGlobal}" var="statClient">
<cewolf:param name="${statClient.siteName}"value="${requestScope.colorMap[statClient.siteCode]}"/>
</c:forEach>
</cewolf:chartpostprocessor>
</cewolf:chart>
```

As you can see I would like to dynamically create the cewolf param line but I get this error:

```
Error 500: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag
incompatible with de.laures.cewolf.taglib.tags.Parameterized.
```

Any idea how I could make it work ?

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the latest released version of cewolf (1.1.4); it has a fix specifically for making core JSTL tags work in parameterized tags.